# jQuery get values from current form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello everyone I'm working on a project and I'm pretty sure I've made a rather large mistake. Basically I have some PHP code that retrieves some values from a database, and each row gets its own  in a table. Then each one has a button that deletes it, which shows a small dropdown form asking for some details along with a submit button. However, I for some reason wasn't thinking that there would be multiple forms, and have each input an id, resulting in multiple elements having the same id.

So, in JavaScript, an AJAX request is made when a user submits deleting a row, and the values from the form (values are found by the ID of the input) are sent as POST variables to a PHP script. Since I'm doing this, the AJAX request only works if they're deleting the first row, but not any under that.

So, this HTML is output by PHP to add a dropdown form to each row:

```
<td class='dropdown'><a class='dropdown-toggle' href='#' data-toggle='dropdown'><button class='btn btn-warning'>Kick</button></a>
<div class='dropdown-menu' style='padding:15px; width:340px'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <form id='delete-form'>
            <label for='delete-reason'>Reason: </label>
            <input class='form-control' id='delete-reason' name='delete-reason'>
            <input type='hidden' id='delete-id' name='delete-id' value='". $value['Name'] ."''>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type='submit' id='delete-submit' name='delete-submit' value='Delete ". $value['Name'] ."' class='btn btn-default'>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I use this JavaScript to submit the form to send the data from the form to a PHP script by an AJAX request.

```
$("#delete-form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault() // stop form from submitting
var reason = $("#delete-reason").val();
var id = $("#delete-id").val()

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/ajax.php',
    data: { 
        deletereason: player,
        deleteid: id
    },
    success: function(response){
        $("#delete-result").append(response);
        $("#delete-result").fadeIn(500);
    }
})
```

})

So, like I said, it only works on the first row because on the others, it just gets the values of the first found input with that id. And when I do it on any row besides the first, it adds the values as a query string, which doesn't do anything because well, it's not supposed to.

However I don't really know how to make it where it would get the values from the current form, not the others, and that's why I'm here.

I understand this is all pretty confusing and if you need me to clarify anything or explain more I'd be happy to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have unique id for each `form` and `input` element and then follow the answer provided by @ArunPJohny. But if you cannot have unique id for each element then follow below code

```
$(".form-group form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() // stop form from submitting
    var reason = $(this).find("input[name='delete-reason']").val();
    var id = $(this).find("input[name='delete-id']").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/ajax.php',
        data: {
            deletereason: player,
            deleteid: id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#delete-result").append(response);
            $("#delete-result").fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok I think this will work but for some reason, one of the inputs is not in the form when I inspect element, so the value isnt sent. But it is in the form in my code, but the browser puts it outside. Very weird. Probably a mistake I made, I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok awesome got it to work (inputs werent inside div, my bad). Thank you!